# Second cohomology group

Tags: group-cohomology

Dear Forum,

Let A be an associative division algebra (i.e. a skew field), G  a subgroup of the multiplicative group of A and E an extension of the additive group A+ of A by G such that G acts on A+ by multiplication in A. Is it true that E always splits? In other words is H^(G,A)=0? Best wishes, V.D. Mazurov

Comment: Could you please use the LaTeX environment when writing math formulae?

Comment: If $A$ is a finite field, the answer is yes (see Serre's Local Fields, Prop. 8). But you probably know this already.